# Getting data from sentences with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the demo version of what I am trying to achieve:

I have a lot of `strings` that are similar to these:

- Usually I buy apples for a 1.5-3 dollars.
- This month oranges cost from 2 dollars - 3 dollars.

I want using loop and regular expression get data from these sentences. Data like, product name (`apples`,`oranges`,other) and the price (`1.5-3`; `2-3`).

Which for each loop I would push to array like `product` and `price`.

**What is the right way to do it?**

**Note:** There can be only **apples** and **oranges** and program **knows it**.
*Note: The expected output is two arrays with products and numbers.*

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: They're similar to those or they're always in that specific format? Where do the strings come from?

Comment: The are all in that specific format.

Comment: I just don't want to write many `if` statements and check if the word is in the sentence, so I'm asking for an alternative way.

Comment: And where do the strings you're checking come from? Are they already in an array in your code? Are they typed in by the user? Read from a file? Sounds like you know what you want to do - use a loop and regular expressions - so what specifically is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @Anthony Grist: The thing that stopping me is that I need apples to go to db sell of apples and oranges to db sell of oranges. And I am trying to avoid multiple if statements if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
var str = "Usually I buy apples for a 1.5-3 dollars.", array = [];
array.push(str.match(/apple|orange/)[0] + 's'); // fruit
array.push(str.match(/[\d\.]+\D+\d+/)[0].replace(/[^\.\d]+/g,"-")); // price
console.log(array); // result
```

Comment: yeah, but is there a way to add apples to one array and oranges to another, without making a lot of if statements (a lot, if you have 20 fruits not 2)?